# std::atomic_is_lock_free(shared_ptr<T>*) didn't compile

Tags: c++, c++11

My simple code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>

int main(void) {
    std::shared_ptr<int> p = std::make_shared<int>(5);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::atomic_is_lock_free(&p) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But compile error:

> a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   a.cpp:7:60: error: no matching function for call to 'atomic_is_lock_free(std::shared_ptr*)'
>     std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::atomic_is_lock_free(&p) << std::endl;
>                                                               ^
>   a.cpp:7:60: note: candidates are:
>   In file included from a.cpp:2:0:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/atomic:804:5: note: template bool std::atomic_is_lock_free(const std::atomic<_ITp>*)
>        atomic_is_lock_free(const atomic<_ITp>* __a) noexcept
>        ^
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/atomic:804:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   a.cpp:7:60: note:   'std::shared_ptr' is not derived from 'const std::atomic<_ITp>'
>     std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::atomic_is_lock_free(&p) << std::endl;
>                                                               ^
>   In file included from a.cpp:2:0:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/atomic:809:5: note: template bool std::atomic_is_lock_free(const volatile std::atomic<_ITp>*)
>        atomic_is_lock_free(const volatile atomic<_ITp>* __a) noexcept
>        ^
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/atomic:809:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   a.cpp:7:60: note:   'std::shared_ptr' is not derived from 'const volatile std::atomic<_ITp>'
>     std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::atomic_is_lock_free(&p) << std::endl;

There is no `template <class T> bool atomic_is_lock_free( const std::shared_ptr<T>* p );` overload. As [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) say, there is. There must be a mistake in my code, could anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: That overload is missing in `<atomic>`, file a bug report.

Comment: @Zeta It seems yes. http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57250 The shared_ptr's atomic test function isn't complete until gcc v4.9.0