# Why doesn't atomic_is_lock_free link correctly on mac?

Tags: c++, xcode, multithreading, llvm, stdatomic

I'm trying to run [this example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_is_lock_free) on mac:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <atomic>

struct A { int a[100]; };
struct B { int x, y; };
int main()
{
    std::atomic<A> a;
    std::atomic<B> b;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << "std::atomic<A> is lock free? "
              << std::atomic_is_lock_free(&a) << '\n'
              << "std::atomic<B> is lock free? "
              << std::atomic_is_lock_free(&b) << '\n';
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___atomic_is_lock_free", referenced from:
      std::__1::__atomic_base<main::B, false>::is_lock_free() const volatile in lock_free_main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Same thing for [this example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free).

I noticed if I change `Struct A` to only have one or two `int`s it does link. Looks like it won't link when the result is not true, but why doesn't it link? Seems like a bug to me.

I found some older questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669757/stdatomic-is-lock-freeshared-ptrt-didnt-compile) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891523/undefined-reference-atomic-is-lock-free-with-xcode-8-2-1), which makes me think the bug should have been resolved by now.

Below is the version of my compiler:

```
 $> g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: try adding `-latomic` to your linker command

Comment: I get this:
`ld: library not found for -lpatomic
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

The function call `atomic_is_lock_free` compiles and links correctly if instead of `int a[100];` I only have `int a;`

Answer (score 0):

Use "is_always_lock_free" instead.

```
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << "std::atomic<A> is lock free? "
              << a.is_always_lock_free << '\n'
              << "std::atomic<B> is lock free? "
              << b.is_always_lock_free << '\n';
```

You may need to define "__cpp_lib_atomic_is_always_lock_free" in addition as it's yet proposal to standard.

Actual problem, that "atomic_is_lock_free" run in compile time, at least for Mac platform)